# Postgres: SELECT AS not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

using this query I get an error and can't figure out how to solve.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
      (SELECT 1), (SELECT  2) 
     )
```

Error:

```
syntax error at or near ","
```

Comment: `select * from (values (1), (2)) as t (id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra parentheses.  I would also suggest aliases:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 as a) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 2 as b) y;
```

Or if the subqueries return only one row and one column:

```
SELECT (SELECT 1), (SELECT 2);
```